# elements do not reposition properly after screen is tapped and keyboard disappears (Webapp)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a webapp using jquery, html and css and testing on an iPad mini and an android device. I have a couple of text input boxes, when I click on them, the keyboard pops up and the elements all move up as they should. If I hit the 'hide keyboard' button on the soft keyboard itself, the keyboard hides and everything repositions itself properly. If on the other hand I tap the screen else where, the keyboard hides, but some of the elements don't resize themselves or reposition themselves. When I swipe down on the app , the page refreshes itself and all the elements are back to normal.

Anyone have any clues as to whats going on and how I can fix it? If not, does anyone know how I can make sure the keyboard only hides when the hide button is hit and no other time?

Thanks